# SVG background-image unsharp on Chrome only (displays correct on Firefox and Safari)

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, background-image, background-repeat

I don't understand why when using an SVG image as background-image with background-repeat looks so unsharp on Chrome, but it look more than fine on Safari or Firefox. Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ella301/pen/MWjymvG) reproducing the issue.

```
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-size: max(100%, 1080px);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-image: url('bg.svg');
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Chrome](https://ibb.co/Vv8W6Yt)
[Firefox](https://ibb.co/p208rWL)

As you can notice, in the above links OR directly in the Chrome or Safari browsers, the curves are unsharp in Chrome (why?), but they look clean and sharp in Firefox (same in Safari).

I can't believe that in 2020 Chrome is so bad at using SVG image as background.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks! Take care!

Comment: Why not report your testcase to Chrome's bugtracker?

Comment: Try shape-rendering: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: It must be related to Chrome on Mac. It looks fine on Win10.